# How do you write special characters in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters

So, I am trying to see if the XML input starts with < or > as < and > respectively, but I cannot get it to even compile because of the special characters.

So

```
<ENAME>"&lt;ADAMS"</ENAME>
```

should become

```
employeeName: <ADAMS>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="ename" select="ENAME"/> 
"employeeName": "<xsl:value-of select="$ename"/><xsl:if test="starts- 
with($ename,&gt;)">&lt;</xsl:if><xsl:if test="starts- 
with($ename,&lt;)">&gt;</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: (1) XML, (2) XSLT, and (3) Desired output

Comment: Are you producing text output or XML output? ie what is the `<xsl:output method=???/>`

Comment: The output is text

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way this could be done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="dQuote">"</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="ENAME">
    <!-- Remove double quote from the input string -->
    <xsl:variable name="ENAME_MOD" select="translate(.,$dQuote,'')"/>
    <xsl:text>employeeName:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ENAME_MOD"/>
    <!-- If the string starts with &lt; then add the &gt; at the end -->
    <xsl:if test="starts-with($ENAME_MOD,'&lt;')">&gt;</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkf